# Unix like file system and directory flag (CPIO)

Tags: unix, permissions

I cannot understand how to know if the entry is a directory in a CPIO file (which is based on Unix). For example the `c_mode`s of different files in octal :

```
120644 --> Link     --> 1010 000 110 100 100 [lrw-r--r--]

120750 --> Link     --> 1010 000 111 101 000 [lrwxr-x---]

040750 --> Directory--> 0100 000 111 101 000 [drwxr-x---]

040755 --> Directory--> 0100 000 111 101 101 [drwxr-xr-x]

100644 --> File     --> 1000 000 110 100 100 [-rw-r--r--]

100750 --> File     --> 1000 000 111 101 000 [-rwxr-x---]
```

I understand how the `r`, `w` and `x` are calculated but not those leading `d`, `l` and `-`. (from `1010` --> `l` etc.). Also, I saw different values of the same charachter (i.e. in place of `l` or `b`) in the Wikipedia. I can't find a good article explaining those directory and link flags along with their appropriate octal (or binary) values in the web! Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer myself. I looked at the file [`stat.h`](http://unix.superglobalmegacorp.com/Net2/newsrc/sys/stat.h.html) and understood it.